# How is it handled when two opposing players are gripping the basketball?

Tags: basketball

Does this only happen when kids play?

I have not seen this happen in adult leagues and when I play with friends nobody does this.  (We are adults).  But it happens at every game when my son plays (He is a kid).

Comment: It results in a jump ball in the NBA, change of possession in FIBA and NCAA.  It happens on every competition level, including frequently in the NBA.

Answer (score 2):

This is a "held ball"; quoting from the [FIBA rules, 12.1.2](http://www.fiba.com/documents/2015/Official_Basketball_Rules_2014_Y.pdf):

> A held ball occurs when one or more players from opposing teams have one or
> both hands firmly on the ball so that neither player can gain control without undue roughness.

This results in a jump ball situation (12.3):

> A jump ball situation occurs when:
>
> - A held ball is called.

Somewhat confusingly under FIBA rules, a jump ball *situation* does not result in a jump ball, but instead teams alternating possession on a throw-in (12.5.1):

> In all jump ball situations teams will alternate possession of the ball for a throw-in at the place nearest to where the jump ball situation occurs.

Under [NBA rules](https://turnernbahangtime.files.wordpress.com/2015/11/official-nba-rule-book-2015-16.pdf), it is also a held ball (Rule 4.VI) but does actually result in a jump ball (Rule 6.VI).